Multi-shot/collage camera app Android
I'm looking for an app which allows to shoot more photos in a row and then that combines the pictures in one. I tried some apps based on timer-shooting but I would prefer something manual. In other words, my purpose is to shoot 3 or more photos to parts of a plant (eg. Leaves, flower, seeds) and obtain a single picture. I was thinking about a mix between a camera app and a collage maker app so i.e.: shoot three photos, collage them, decide the position of the photos in the collage, save Do you know something like that?

Bunch of apps like that exist. It depends on what exactly the goal is.
If combining all the pictures into one bigger one, then you should look for panorama/photosphere stitchers. Like this Bimostitch one. From my experience they aren't great though, you may have better luck looking for online web apps rather than Android ones.
If just combining them into a grid/collage, then e.g. PicCollage could help. It has bunch of template for semi-automation.

PicCollage is the kind of app I was looking for! PicCollage is very good and does the job. I also found a similar app: FunPic. With these apps you can shoot more photos and put them in a grid that can be saved as a single file. I don't know if there's a quality loss during this process. You can put in the grid pictures from your gallery (post-production) or shoot new photos to put in a grid (more dynamic photo combining). FunPic also allows am advanced grid customisation (line width regulation, elements resizing, irregular grids)
